# Topological self-maps of smooth complex hypersufaces in complex projective spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry

This questions if related to a cute article of Beauville where he proves in particular the following theorem:

http://math1.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/endo.pdf

**Theorem.**− A smooth complex projective hypersurface of dimension $\ge 2$ and degree $\ge 3$ admits no endomorphism of degree $>1$.

Here "endomorphism" means a holomorphic self-map and the proof of the theorem uses algebraic geometry bien sure:) . But the following question is not mentioned in the article:

**Question.** What are smooth complex projective hypersufaces in $\mathbb CP^n$ that admit topological self-maps of degree $>1$?

I wonder if this question is trivial and completely answered for $n>2$?

**Added.** The comment of algori settles this question (apperently). But still I wonder for example how one can construct a self-map of a quintic in $\mathbb CP^3$ of degree $>1$.

Comment: aglearner -- as pointed out by Donu Arapura in this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112572/compact-homogeneous-spaces-that-admit-a-self-map-of-degree-1/112585#112585, by a formality argument the answer is "all except curves of genus $\leq 1$"; the argument is applicable since smooth projective hypersurfaces and, more generally, complete intersections are simply-connected unless they are curves by Lefschetz theorem.

Comment: .. erm.. that should have been "all except curves of genus $>1$".

Comment: aglearner -- welcome!

Comment: Hi aglearner, I don't understand your "added"... Proposition 2 of the paper you linked states that if $X$ is a compact manifold, with an endomorphism $f$ of degree $>1$ then the Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X)$ is $<\dim(X)$. But smooth a quintic in $\mathbb P^3$ has ample canonical bundle by adjunction, thus it is of maximal Kodaira dimension.

Comment: diverietti -- that's precisely the point: holomorphic endomorphisms of positive degree don't exist (that's what Beauville proves) but continuous do. The way I understand it, aglearner is asking for an explicit construction of such an endomorphism.